# Performing an EC public key calculation for given secret key gives wrong results

Tags: perl, cryptography, public-key, elliptic-curve

I was trying to understand calculation of EC public key for given secret key. Following this question I was found a [well explained answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480776/how-do-i-obtain-the-public-key-from-an-ecdsa-private-key-in-openssl), but (as often happens) something goes wrong. According to previous answer and [this document](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) I use following Perl script to perform calculation:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::BigInt;

my $d_hex = "18E14A7B6A307F426A94F8114701E7C8E774E7F9A47E2C2035DB29A206321725";
my $d_num = Math::BigInt->new("0x$d_hex");

my $g_hex = "0479BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8";
my $g_num = Math::BigInt->new("0x$g_hex");

my $q_num = $d_num->copy()->bmul($g_num);
my $q_hex = $q_num->as_hex();

# Expect: 0x0450863ad64a87ae8a2fe83c1af1a8403cb53f53e486d8511dad8a04887e5b23522cd470243453a299fa9e77237716103abc11a1df38855ed6f2ee187e9c582ba6
# Result: 0x479be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798611c24f290d443a7c839f40d5512f071e48c9c424b038039d222fa320142ebdd

print "$q_hex\n";
```

Here is expected result means a result of calculation using code written in C from previously founded answer. As you can see, results is different. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not used to Perl but i cannot see you initializing or using a cyclic group. Elliptic curve operations and asymmetric crypto in general are (mostly) always performed in a cyclic group

Comment: Thank you, I was found a nice library written in PHP where I found how to deal with it. I will post right answer there when I am done.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a PHP [library](https://github.com/tuaris/CryptoCurrencyPHP) that can generate addresses from private key, and wrote an [example code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8ad5a5766ba754e57fd5?) in Perl that based on this PHP code. It weird, but works is some cases. Anyway, this is enough for me to understand about how it works.