# How to pass C NULL to XS based function?

Tags: perl, xs

I am trying to use Crypt::OpenSSL::EC::EC_POINT::mul() function from Crypt::OpenSSL::EC module. It has such C prototype:

```
int EC_POINT_mul(const EC_GROUP *group, EC_POINT *r, const BIGNUM *n, const EC_POINT *q, const BIGNUM *m, BN_CTX *ctx)
```

And I need to pass NULL, NULL instead of `EC_POINT *q`, `const BIGNUM *m` as it made here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12482384/3090865

But this module has such typemap:

```
INPUT
BIGNUM
    if( ! SvROK( $arg ) ) { croak( \"argument is not an object\" ); }
    $var = (${type}) SvIV( SvRV( $arg ) );

EC_METHOD
    if( ! SvROK( $arg ) ) { croak( \"argument is not an object\" ); }
    $var = (${type}) SvIV( SvRV( $arg ) );

EC_GROUP
    if( ! SvROK( $arg ) ) { croak( \"argument is not an object\" ); }
    $var = (${type}) SvIV( SvRV( $arg ) );

EC_POINT
    if( ! SvROK( $arg ) ) { croak( \"argument is not an object\" ); }
    $var = (${type}) SvIV( SvRV( $arg ) );

EC_KEY
    if( ! SvROK( $arg ) ) { croak( \"argument is not an object\" ); }
    $var = (${type}) SvIV( SvRV( $arg ) );
```

So, if i'll pass undef or 0, i'll get "argument is not an object" error.
Is it possible to make what I want without changing this module? Maybe I can create NULL-based object somehow?

Comment: "I need to pass NULL, NULL instead of EC_POINT *q, const BIGNUM *m" --  This doesn't make sense.  What are thinking that the NULL `q` corresponds to in EC terminology?  The point at infinity?  Same question for `m`?  Does NULL correspond to 0?  I ask because there may be a better way of trying to do whatever you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the typemap, passing a reference to zero `\0` should work:

```
Crypt::OpenSSL::EC::EC_POINT::mul($group, $r, $n, \0, \0, $ctx);
```

Comment: Addeding `use constant NULL => \0;` would make things nicer :)

Comment: Thank you, that works! If the message was "argument is not a reference" I could guess :)