# How to generate ECDSA private and public key for DNSSEC using OpenSSL?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, elliptic-curve, dnssec

I am trying to create private and public keys for DNSSEC algorithm 13:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main()
{
     EC_KEY *eckey = NULL;
     const EC_POINT *pub_key = NULL;
     const EC_GROUP *group = NULL;
     const BIGNUM *res;
     BN_CTX *ctx;

     ctx = BN_CTX_new();

     eckey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
     EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey);

     res = EC_KEY_get0_private_key(eckey);
     printf("Private: %s\n", BN_bn2hex(res));

     group = EC_KEY_get0_group(eckey);
     pub_key  = EC_KEY_get0_public_key(eckey);
     printf("Public: %s\n", EC_POINT_point2hex(group, pub_key, 4, ctx));

     return 0;
}
```

Testing:

```
$ gcc -lcrypto test.c
$ ./a.out | perl -MMIME::Base64 -pe 's/(?<=:\s)(.+)/encode_base64(pack "H*", $1)/e'
Private: PgO6atAv+YEuyvRvvuTyDf8kz7vp/hQKNdKJyvVVBoQ=

Public: BAPe3AhjpcMCQPpZzZeFRwVuR4su/cmd3Vl2zn+i2izEWxOdbww/3fw4yAi0yQUUhlvXZqTnaeol
OK03LOdsKkk=
```

(Perl line just converts hex notation to binary and then to base64.)

But if I set this private key to DNS server (which accepts only private key and generates public on the fly) it returns public key which doesn't match this one returned by OpenSSL

```
Key inside DNS server (PowerDNS):
Private-key-format: v1.2
Algorithm: 13 (ECDSAP256SHA256)
PrivateKey: PgO6atAv+YEuyvRvvuTyDf8kz7vp/hQKNdKJyvVVBoQ=

$ dig @127.0.0.1 +short example.com DNSKEY
257 3 13 A97cCGOlwwJA+lnNl4VHBW5Hiy79yZ3dWXbOf6LaLMRbE51vDD/d/DjI CLTJBRSGW9dmpOdp6iU4rTcs52wqSQ==
```

So, I got `A97cCGOlwwJA+lnNl4VHBW5Hiy79yZ3dWXbOf6LaLMRbE51vDD/d/DjI CLTJBRSGW9dmpOdp6iU4rTcs52wqSQ==` which doesn't match `BAPe3AhjpcMCQPpZzZeFRwVuR4su/cmd3Vl2zn+i2izEWxOdbww/3fw4yAi0yQUUhlvXZqTnaeol
    OK03LOdsKkk=`.

Why this happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two values are actually the same, except that OpenSSL adds a `0x04` prefix byte. This is a standard format, the `0x04` indicates that the point is in *uncompressed* form, it is followed by 32 bytes of the X coordinate of the point and then 32 bytes for the Y coordinate, for 65 bytes total.

The DNS entry just has the X and Y coordinates, without the prefix byte, for 64 bytes total.

Since this extra byte is the *first* byte, it changes the alignment of the base 64 encoding and the two encoded values look quite different.

Comparing the values, first your value from OpenSSL:

```
$ echo BAPe3AhjpcMCQPpZzZeFRwVuR4su/cmd3Vl2zn+i2izEWxOdbww/3fw4yAi0yQUUhlvXZqTnaeolOK03LOdsKkk= | base64 -D | xxd
00000000: 0403 dedc 0863 a5c3 0240 fa59 cd97 8547  .....c...@.Y...G
00000010: 056e 478b 2efd c99d dd59 76ce 7fa2 da2c  .nG......Yv....,
00000020: c45b 139d 6f0c 3fdd fc38 c808 b4c9 0514  .[..o.?..8......
00000030: 865b d766 a4e7 69ea 2538 ad37 2ce7 6c2a  .[.f..i.%8.7,.l*
00000040: 49
```

Next the value from DNS:

```
echo A97cCGOlwwJA+lnNl4VHBW5Hiy79yZ3dWXbOf6LaLMRbE51vDD/d/DjICLTJBRSGW9dmpOdp6iU4rTcs52wqSQ== | base64 -D | xxd
00000000: 03de dc08 63a5 c302 40fa 59cd 9785 4705  ....c...@.Y...G.
00000010: 6e47 8b2e fdc9 9ddd 5976 ce7f a2da 2cc4  nG......Yv....,.
00000020: 5b13 9d6f 0c3f ddfc 38c8 08b4 c905 1486  [..o.?..8.......
00000030: 5bd7 66a4 e769 ea25 38ad 372c e76c 2a49  [.f..i.%8.7,.l*I
```

You can see that except for the extra `0x04` the two values are the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was deep-deep inside bind9 sourcecode before saw your answer and found the same (I think at the same time you typed this): they make copy of the key without first byte: https://source.isc.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=bind9.git;a=blob;f=lib/dns/opensslecdsa_link.c;h=42b929a33ea4863fa07d52f435e3bd89beaf44c2;hb=HEAD#l391  . But I didn't know the reason. And your answer explains this very well. Thanks again.