# Implicit declaration of function 'BN_init' error

Tags: c, openssl, bitcoin

I was checking out how to generate public keys from a private bitcoin address.
I found the following page:
[How do I obtain the public key from an ECDSA private key in OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480776/how-do-i-obtain-the-public-key-from-an-ecdsa-private-key-in-openssl)

But when I try to compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror -O3 -o public_key public_key.c -lcrypto`, I get the following errors:

```
public_key.c: In function 'generate_pubic_key':
public_key.c:26:13: error: storage size of 'start' isn't known
      BIGNUM start;
             ^~~~~
public_key.c:32:6: error: implicit declaration of function 'BN_init' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
      BN_init(&start);
      ^~~~~~~
public_key.c:26:13: error: unused variable 'start' [-Werror=unused-variable]
      BIGNUM start;
             ^~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

I have OpenSSL installed and haven't had any programing errors related to it, until now.  Can someone point out what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Chances are that you have openssl 1.1.0 or later, and that you are using previously deprecated and now fully removed functionality. See answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using <strike>deprecated</strike> removed API.

As per [BN_new(3)](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:BN_new(3)) man page:

REMOVED FUNCTIONALITY
 void BN_init(BIGNUM *);

> BN_init() is no longer available as of OpenSSL 1.1.0. It was used to
>   initialize an existing uninitialized BIGNUM. Typically this would be
>   done as follows:
>
> ```
>  BIGNUM a;
>  BN_init(&a);
> ```
>
> Applications should replace use of BN_init with BN_new instead:
>
> ```
>  BIGNUM *a;
>  a = BN_new();
>  if(!a) /* Handle error */
>  ...
>  BN_free(a);
> ```